# Javascript->Iterating in for loop.Changes in Child variable changing parent variable

Tags: javascript

I have one parent array and I am taking a filtered array(child array) from parent array.Up on changing the child array my parent array is changing.Can you please help how can I have the same parent array unchanged.

```
let parentArray=[
  { "id":"1", "Package":"Tes1", "Version":"20080210-1.1", "Maintainer":"Stefano Canepa"},
  { "id":"1", "Package":"Test2", "Version":"7.0-1", "Maintainer":"Debian Games Team"},
  { "id":"1", "Package":"Test3", "Version":"20080210-1.1", "Maintainer":"Stefano Canepa"},
  { "id":"1", "Package":"Test4", "Version":"7.0-1", "Maintainer":"Debian Games Team"},
  { "id":"5", "Package":"Tdst5", "Version":"20080210-1.1", "Maintainer":"Stefano Canepa"},
  { "id":"6", "Package":"Test6", "Version":"7.0-1", "Maintainer":"Debian Games Team"},
  { "id":"7", "Package":"Test7", "Version":"20080210-1.1", "Maintainer":"Stefano Canepa"},
  { "id":"8", "Package":"Test8", "Version":"7.0-1", "Maintainer":"Debian Games Team"}
];
let childArray=parentArray.filter(x=>x.id=="1");
console.log("before"+JSON.stringify(parentArray));
childArray.forEach(value=>value.Package="changed")
console.log("after"+JSON.stringify(parentArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

`filter()` doesn't make copies of the objects. It just gives you a new array with references to the exact same objects in `parentArray`.

If you want copies in `childArray` you'll need to do it yourself. One way to do this is to use `map()` together with `Object.assign()`, which will make shallow copies of your objects:

```js
let parentArray=[
    { "id":"1", "Package":"Tes1", "Version":"20080210-1.1", "Maintainer":"Stefano Canepa"},
    { "id":"1", "Package":"Test2", "Version":"7.0-1", "Maintainer":"Debian Games Team"},
    { "id":"1", "Package":"Test3", "Version":"20080210-1.1", "Maintainer":"Stefano Canepa"},
    { "id":"1", "Package":"Test4", "Version":"7.0-1", "Maintainer":"Debian Games Team"},
    { "id":"5", "Package":"Tdst5", "Version":"20080210-1.1", "Maintainer":"Stefano Canepa"},
    { "id":"6", "Package":"Test6", "Version":"7.0-1", "Maintainer":"Debian Games Team"},
    { "id":"7", "Package":"Test7", "Version":"20080210-1.1", "Maintainer":"Stefano Canepa"},
    { "id":"8", "Package":"Test8", "Version":"7.0-1", "Maintainer":"Debian Games Team"}
  ];
 
 let childArray=parentArray.filter(x=>x.id=="1")
      .map(obj => Object.assign({}, obj))  // make copies
      
 console.log("before"+JSON.stringify(parentArray));
 childArray.forEach(value=>value.Package="changed")
 console.log("after"+JSON.stringify(parentArray));
```

Comment: there is no change of code apart from the `map`. i tested the OP code and `parentArray` does change. How can it happen?

Comment: @david I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. The only change in my example is `map` if loops over each object and returns a copy. The point is that in the original Parent and Child arrays both point to the *same* objects in memory. When you change it in one place, it changes in the other.

Comment: just to highlight: "making shallow copy" means that all nested objects inside array item will still be "copied" by reference. So `Object.assign` should be safe to use only if your objects are flat. Otherwise OP will need `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))` to get in-deep copy.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Thank you so much.That has worked out for me.